# Conditioning on an irrelevant variable in a martingale control problem

Tags: pr.probability, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-differential-equations, martingales

Suppose I have two independent Brownian motions $B^1_t, B^2_t$ and $\mathbb F_t$ be the natural filtration generated by them. Let $T > 0$ be a fixed finite number. Let $q_t$ be a $[-1,1]$ valued $\mathbb{F}_t$ martingale that the analyst controls.

Let $\mathcal Q$ be the set of $[-1,1]$ valued $\mathbb F_t$ martingales. The control problem is: $$\sup_{q \in \mathcal Q} E_{0,q_0} f(q_T, B^1_T)$$

where $q_0$ is the value of $q$ at time $0$. $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ is linear in each argument. As we can see, the objective function does not depend on $B^2_t$.

I would conjecture that, given the linearity of $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ in each of its argument and no dependence on $B^2_t$, that we can restrict attention to $[-1,1]$ valued $\sigma(B^1_t)$ martingales where $\sigma(B^1_t)$ is a coarser filtration generated only by $B^1_t$.

Does that sound like a reasonable conjecture? And how can I argue this if true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true. For any $q \in \mathcal{Q}$, you may define $\tilde{q}$ as the *optional projection* of $q$ onto the filtration generated by $B^1$. This $\tilde{q}$ remains a martingale and achieves the same value thanks to linearity of $f$. More generally, using Jensen’s inequality, your conjecture is true as long as $f$ is concave in $q$.

This notion of *optional projection* is well established in stochastic analysis. Essentially, it gives you a process $\tilde{q}$ adapted to the $B^1$ filtration, which I’ll denote $F^1$, satisfying $\tilde{q}_t = E[q_t | F^1_t]$ almost surely for each $t$. A google search should lead you easily to references on how it is defined and the theorem stating that the optional projection of a martingale remains a martingale.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sounds exactly the kind of a thing I needed. I will read more on optional projection.